# C++ writing object data to file

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented

I'm trying to write a program that stores usernames and passwords. So I have created a Record class. Each record has an id, title, username, and password field. I want to write each record to a text file.

However, I am having some issues. When I compile I get the following errors.

```
'Record::getTitle': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
'Record::getUsername': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
'Record::getPassword': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

The problem:

```
writeToFile(firstRecord.getTitle, firstRecord.getUsername, firstRecord.getPassword);
```

The getTitle(and others) return a string. So I am not sure why this isn't working. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Complete code (so far) below..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

string GetInput();
void MainMenu();
void Title();
void AddRecord();
void writeToFile(string title, string username, string password);

class Record {

private:

    string id;
    string title;
    string username;
    string password;
    static int numberOfRecords;

public:

    void setTitle(string title) {
        this->title = title;
    }
    string getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    void setUsername(string username) {
        this->username = username;
    }
    string getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    void setPassword(string password) {
        this->password = password;
    }
    string getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    static int GetNumberOfRecords() {
        return numberOfRecords;
    }
};

struct MenuAction {

    string description;
    function<void()> action;
};

static const map <string, MenuAction> actionTable{

    { "1",{ "Add entry", []() { AddRecord(); } } },
    { "2",{ "Edit entry", []() { cout << "Edit entry" << "\n";  } } },
    { "q",{ "Quit", []() { cout << "Quit" << "\n";  } } }
};

int main() {

    Title();
    MainMenu();

    return 0;
}

void Title() {

    cout << "======================================\n"
            "|              Database              |\n"
            "======================================\n\n";
}

void MainMenu() {

    for (auto const& x : actionTable) {
        cout << x.first << ". " << (x.second).description << "\n";
    }

    string input;

    while (actionTable.count(input) == 0) {
        input = GetInput();
    }

    actionTable.at(input).action();
}

void AddRecord() {

    cout << "============= Add Record ============" << endl << endl;

    string id;
    string title;
    string username;
    string password;

    cout << "Title: ";
    getline(cin, title);
    cout << "Username: ";
    getline(cin, username);
    cout << "Password: ";
    getline(cin, password);

    Record firstRecord;
    firstRecord.setTitle(title);
    firstRecord.setUsername(username);
    firstRecord.setPassword(password);

    writeToFile(firstRecord.getTitle, firstRecord.getUsername, firstRecord.getPassword);
}

string GetInput() {

    string s = "";

    cout << ">> ";
    getline(cin, s);

    return s;
}

void writeToFile(string title, string username, string password) {

    ofstream outFile;

    outFile.open("database.txt", ios_base::app);
    outFile << title << "\t" << username << "\t" << password << "\n";

    cout << "============= Record Added To Database ============" << endl;
}
```

Feel free to comment or nag other portions of my code :)

Comment: What's the deal? Why is this getting down voted? I'm fairly new here and to c++ in general. Is there some protocol I'm not following?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Here we review real, working code and try to make it better. This is not the right place to ask for help fixing your code. For this, [so] is better suited (but be sure to consult their [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) first).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**firstRecord.getTitle, firstRecord.getUsername, firstRecord.getPassword**

The params you are passing into your function are not properties, they are functions (getters) of your object.

You need to access them like functions:
writeToFile(firstRecord.getTitle(), firstRecord.getUsername(), firstRecord.getPassword());

Comment: Wow. That was an embarrassing mistake. Thanks for the help!